# How to pass data from parent to children with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I have a simple modal in which I have a form on submit I display errors now I want to pass these errors to the children component.

Here is a simplified parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from 'components/Functional/Input';

function Parent() {
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
    const handleSubmit = async e => {
            const formData = new FormData();
    }

    return (
        <Modal handleSubmit={handleSubmit}>
           <Input setErrors={errors} ></Input>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

Here is my children component

```
import React from 'react'

function Input({errors}) {
    const [field, setField] =useState('');

    console.log('errors', errors)
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text"  onChange={e => setField(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Input
```

Now when I submit the data with errors, the `console.log('errors', errors)` in the children component I get `undefined`

What is wrong here?

Comment: Typo.  You're passing a prop called `setErrors` but the component is expecting a prop called `errors`.

Comment: yes ur right , thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to props name. You're passing from parent a property called `setErrors` while in child component you're looking for `errors`. Try to rename property from `setErrors` to `errors` or simply read `setErrors` from `<Input />` component

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo in your input component. You set the prop `setErrors` but your component expects `errors`. If you use plain javascript you should use proptypes to ensure this doesn't happen.

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function Input({errors}) {
    const [field, setField] =useState('');

    console.log('errors', errors)
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text"  onChange={e => setField(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
    )
}

Input.propTypes = {
    errors: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
};

export default Input
```

See [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)